# d3 v6 adding nodes on click

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to get in touch with the D3v6. Functions which I used to work with D3v4 seems obsolete now or are in need of different constructor. Anyway I am trying to add a node during a simple click event. `addNode()`

The ID is generator by the length of the array + 1, further I pushing the element to the array and create/merge the new node. Afterwards the simulation is restarted and the alpha heated. Still no clue why I get such a result as shown. Its like the nodes freeze and the links are moving instead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 v.0.0.1</title>
 
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    circle {
        fill: whitesmoke;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 2px
    }

    line {
        stroke: black;
    }

    svg {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <svg> </svg>
    </div>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    
    var width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight

var graph = {
    "nodes": [
        { "id": 1 }, 
        { "id": 2 }, 
        { "id": 3 }, 
        { "id": 4 }, 
        { "id": 5 }
    ],
    "links": [
        { "source": 1, "target": 2 },
        { "source": 2, "target": 3 },
        { "source": 3, "target": 4 },
        { "source": 4, "target": 5 },
        { "source": 5, "target": 1 }
    ]
}

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
        svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
    }))
    .append("g")

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(100))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-400))
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")

var node = svg.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .on("click", addNode)
    .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )


    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation
        .force("link")
        .links(graph.links)


function ticked() {

    link
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });
 
}

function dragStarted(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged (event, d) {
    d.fx = event.x;
    d.fy = event.y;
}

function dragEnded(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = undefined;
    d.fy = undefined;
}

function addNode(d) {
    var newID = graph.nodes.length + 1
    
    graph.nodes.push({"id": newID})

    node = svg.selectAll(".nodes")
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .merge(node)

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);
    
    //reheat the simulation
    simulation.alpha(0.3).restart()
}
    
    
   
    </script>

   
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not enter items correctly - you don't have an enter statement. You also don't have any elements with class `node`, so your initial selection is empty, you want to select `circle`s  (or apply a class to them). Try:

```
    node = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .merge(node)
```

*The nodes are unbound, so they'll float away. Also, a drag is a long click, so you can't drag a node without creating a new one as is.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>D3v6 v.0.0.1</title>
 
    <!-- call external d3.js framework -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style>
    circle {
        fill: whitesmoke;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 2px
    }

    line {
        stroke: black;
    }

    svg {
        background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="content">
        <svg> </svg>
    </div>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
    
    <script>
    
    var width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight

var graph = {
    "nodes": [
        { "id": 1 }, 
        { "id": 2 }, 
        { "id": 3 }, 
        { "id": 4 }, 
        { "id": 5 }
    ],
    "links": [
        { "source": 1, "target": 2 },
        { "source": 2, "target": 3 },
        { "source": 3, "target": 4 },
        { "source": 4, "target": 5 },
        { "source": 5, "target": 1 }
    ]
}

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function (event) {
        svg.attr("transform", event.transform)
    }))
    .append("g")

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(100))
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-400))
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("line")

var node = svg.selectAll(".nodes")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 20)
    .on("click", addNode)
    .call(d3.drag()
                .on("start", dragStarted)
                .on("drag", dragged)
                .on("end", dragEnded)
            )


    simulation
        .nodes(graph.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    simulation
        .force("link")
        .links(graph.links)


function ticked() {

    link
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });

    node
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });
 
}

function dragStarted(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged (event, d) {
    d.fx = event.x;
    d.fy = event.y;
}

function dragEnded(event, d) {
    if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = undefined;
    d.fy = undefined;
}

function addNode(d) {
    var newID = graph.nodes.length + 1
    
    graph.nodes.push({"id": newID})

    node = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("r", 20)
        .merge(node)

    simulation.nodes(graph.nodes);
    simulation.force("link").links(graph.links);
    
    //reheat the simulation
    simulation.alpha(0.3).restart()
}
    
    
   
    </script>

   
</body>

</html>
```